# Java dynamic get set methods

Tags: java, methods, setter, getter, getter-setter

Hello I was wondering how I can make the most dynamic get set methods in a java program I am working on? The program has multiple fields and each field needs to have its own get and set method but I want only one get set method that can get and set any field in the class I want.

```
package kalsi;

public class ContestantInformation {
    String firstName, lastName, city, province, postalCode, streetName, streetNumber, phoneNum, birthDate;

    public ContestantInformation() {    
    }

    public ContestantInformation(String firstName, String lastName, int streetNumber, String streetName, String city,
            String province, String postalCode, int phoneNum, int birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = "" + birthDate;
        this.streetNumber = "" + streetNumber;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.city = city;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.phoneNum = "" + phoneNum;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. There's no good reason to create dynamic getters/setters (which requires the use of reflection) in this case. 2. Any good IDE will auto-generate getters/setters for you.

Comment: @alfasin Thank you for your reply. But if I were to code it how would it be done.

Comment: You can see this https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your IDE to generate `getter/setter` methods. If you are using eclipse then you can do it by going to **Source>generate methods**.

Or alternatively you can use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/index.html) generate getter setter method dynamically. In this case you don't even need to write your `getter/setter` methods. Look at the example -

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class Person {

   @Getter @Setter private String name;
   @Getter @Setter private int age = 10;
 }
```